# How do I insert an IF inside the WHEN NOT MATCHED part of the MERGE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to achieve the part highlighted between '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<' and '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'. I haven't been able to figure out how to do it, but I need to run this on TBs of data and hence I want to figure out a good and fast way to do it

```
PROCEDURE upsert (
    iAttr1 IN NUMBER,
    iId1 IN NUMBER,
    iId1Version IN NUMBER,
    iId2 IN NUMBER,
    iAttr2 IN VARCHAR2,
    iAttr3 IN VARCHAR2,
    iAttr4 IN VARCHAR2,
    iEarliest IN TIMESTAMP,
    iEarliestId IN VARCHAR2,
    iLatest IN TIMESTAMP
    iLatestId IN VARCHAR2,
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE
        INTO mytable a
        USING dual
        ON (a.attr1 = iAttr1 AND a.id1 = iId1 AND a.id1_version = iIdVersion)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (a.attr1, a.id, a.id1_version, a.id2, a.attr2, a.attr3, a.attr4, a.earliest, a.earliest_id, a.latest, a.latest_id)
            VALUES (iAttr1, iId1, iId1Version, iId2, iAttr2, iAttr3, iAttr4, iEarliest, iEarliestId, iLatest, iLatestId)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< what I need
            IF a.earliest > iEarliest THEN
                UPDATE SET
                    a.earliest = iEarliest, 
                    a.earliest_id = iEarliestId;
            END IF;
            IF a.latest < iLatest THEN
                UPDATE SET
                    a.latest = iLatest,
                    a.latest_id = iLatestId;
            END IF;
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> what I need
END upsert;
```

Comment: Is it `IF ELSE` match or both conditions can be matched with single update ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, yes, both conditions can be matched with a single update

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way but we can use `CASE` statement to achieve it,

```
MERGE INTO mytable a
USING dual
ON (a.attr1 = iAttr1 AND a.id1 = iId1 AND a.id1_version = iIdVersion)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a.attr1, a.id, a.id1_version, a.id2, a.attr2, a.attr3, a.attr4, a.earliest, a.earliest_id, a.latest, a.latest_id)
    VALUES (iAttr1, iId1, iId1Version, iId2, iAttr2, iAttr3, iAttr4, iEarliest, iEarliestId, iLatest, iLatestId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET
    a.earliest = case when a.earliest > iEarliest then iEarliest else a.earliest end, 
    a.earliest_id = case when a.earliest > iEarliest then iEarliestId else a.earliest_id end,
    a.latest = case when a.latest < iLatest then iLatest else a.latest end, 
    a.latest_id = case when a.latest < iLatest then iLatestId else a.latest_id end;
```

Comment: Thanks, @sujitmohanty30. The above worked for me. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @Jared, that's nice to hear. You can accept the answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET
        a.earliest = CASE WHEN a.earliest > iEarliest THEN iEarliest ELSE a.earliest END, 
        a.earliest_id = CASE WHEN a.earliest > iEarliest THEN iEarliestId ELSE a.earliest END,
        a.latest = CASE WHEN a.latest < iLatest THEN iLatest ELSE a.latest END  
        a.latest_id = CASE WHEN a.latest < iLatest THEN iLatestID ELSE aLatestID END;
```

Comment: Thanks, @velocity. The above worked for me. Really appreciate the help